# How to create a button in shinyR which event is the same as the polygon drawing toolbar in leaflet map

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, leaflet.draw

I want to create a button in shinyR which event is the same as the polygon drawing toolbar in leaflet map. I'm trying to figure out how to manually trigger events from R to Leaflet polygons. Basically, I want if click on a button in shinyR, I can start drawing a polygon the same way if I did it with the leaflet drawing toolbar.

I send Instructions from R to Javascript like this:

from UI side:

```
    drw <- tags$script(HTML(
    "
    Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler(
    'drw_pol',
     const onCreate =(e)=> {
        var e = document.createEvent('Event');
        e.initEvent('click', true, true);
        var cb = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-draw-draw-polygon');
        return !cb[0].dispatchEvent(e);
     };
    "
    ))
    
    drw,
    tags$button(type="button", id = "polygon_button", 'handler', style='color:#3399FF ;background-color: Transparent',
              class="btn action-button shiny-bound-input"),
    leafletOutput("map")
```

form server side:

```
      hit <- function(){
        onClick={(e)= {onCreate(e)}}
      }
      
      observeEvent(input$polygon_button, {
        function(x) {
          session$sendCustomMessage(
            "drw_pol", hit()
          )
        }
      })
```

Unfortunately, my code does not work.  My biggest challenge is how to send the click event from R to Shiny.  click event is sent from R via the hit() function creater in R. Please can you tell me what did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I come up to a simple solution with the package shinyjs:

in UI:

jspolygon <- "shinyjs.polygon_click = function(){
    var e = document.createEvent('Event');
    e.initEvent('click', true, true);
    var cb = document.getElementsByClassName('leaflet-draw-draw-polygon');
    return !cb[0].dispatchEvent(e);
}"
  useShinyjs(),
  shinyjs::extendShinyjs(text = jspolygon, functions = c("polygon_click"))

in server:

  observeEvent(input$polygon_button, {
    js$polygon_click()
  })
```